# Newtons Law of Cooling is the law of natural growth?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

So Newton's law of cooling states that

$$ \frac{dT}{dt} = k(T - T_s) $$

And in my textbook it says that if we let $$y(t) = (T - T_s)$$

then $$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dT}{dt}$$

Which makes sense so far since $T_s$ is a constant

But then the book says

Thus our differential equation becomes...

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = ky$$

Where in the world did $ky$ come from???

Comment: In the very first equation, did you mean $dT/dt$, rather than $dT/dy$, on the left hand side?

Comment: Woops yes, that was a typo. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's law of cooling would be $$\frac{dT}{d\color{red}{t}}=k(T-T_s)$$
so if we let $y(t)=T-T_s$ then we replace $T-T_s$ on the right-hand side of the equation with $y$ to get $$\frac{dT}{dt}=ky$$ and finally, we use replace $\frac{dT}{dt}$ with $\frac{dy}{dt}$ on the left-hand side of the equation (since these are equal as you say) to obtain $$\frac{dy}{dt}=ky.$$

Comment: Thank you so much Dave :)